# Not every element's class is updated when iterating over an element array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, html

I have a simple JavaScript function that should change the class and therefore the color of 4 buttons when clicked. They do not all change when the "Click me" button is pressed the first time though - only the colours for button1 and button3 change to red. Clicking the "Click me" button again then changes the color of button2 and after another click button4 is updated.

```
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .updatedButton {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function changeColor() {
        var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
        for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(elems[i].getAttribute('id')));
            elems[i].classList.add('updatedButton');
            elems[i].classList.remove('button');
        }
    }
</script>

<button id="button1" class="button">a</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">b</button>
<button id="button3" class="button">c</button>
<button id="button4" class="button">d</button>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Click me</button>
```

I logged to the console the ID of the elements that were inside the loop and this is what I got showing that only certain buttons are being updated.

First click:
"button1" (15:16:52:545)
"button3" (15:16:52:547)

Second click:
"button2" (15:16:55:981)

Third click:
"button4" (15:16:58:841)

I tried reloading the page but the behaviour is consistent. Could anyone explain why this is happening instead of every button changing color on the first button press please?

Comment: Why the `JSON.stringify(...)` call?

Comment: `<button onclick="changeColor">Click me</button>` if you put parens after `changeColor` it will run the function without waiting for onclick to trigger

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns live collection that is changed immediatelly when you remove the class. Use `querySelectorAll` instead.

```js
function changeColor() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(elems[i].getAttribute('id')));
    elems[i].classList.add('updatedButton');
    elems[i].classList.remove('button');
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: green;
}

.updatedButton {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" class="button">a</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">b</button>
<button id="button3" class="button">c</button>
<button id="button4" class="button">d</button>
<button onclick="changeColor()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: In some cases `querySelectorAll()` also returns a live `NodeList`.

Comment: @connexo Plz provide a reference when it does. Because it returns `NodeList` to begin with.

Comment: @connexo _"The Element method `querySelectorAll()` returns a **static (not live)** NodeList representing a list of elements matching the specified group of selectors which are descendants of the element on which the method was called."_

Comment: @YuryTarabanko A `NodeList` can also be _live_: _"In some cases, the NodeList is live, which means that changes in the DOM automatically update the collection. For example, Node.childNodes is live"_ ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList))

Comment: @Andreas It was "to begin with" :) connexo wrote it returns "a live `HTMLCollection`" :)

Comment: You are correct, both of you. Adjusted my comment accordingly.

Comment: @connexo `.querySelectorAll()` won't ever return a live collection: _"The querySelectorAll(selectors) method, when invoked, **must return the static result** of running scope-match a selectors string selectors against context object."_ ([Source](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-parentnode-queryselectorall))

Comment: Good find! I only remembered that in some cases you get something you'd expect to be static by type and it is live despite that. Good thing you pointed me to the exception to sharpen my knowledge!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`, meaning that as soon as you remove the `button` class, it's no longer in the collection.

To prevent that, create a shallow copy in an array initially:

```
var elems = [...document.getElementsByClassName("button")];
```

Depending on what your build environment supports, you can also use `Array.from`:

```
var elems = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("button"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include all the buttons inside one div and assign a class for it then select all buttons inside this class and change the color for all the selected buttons!

Comment: TO is already selecting them with a common class, hence the `.getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you need to use querySelctorAll instead. Check this jsfiddle out.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekcLbwur/11/

```
    function changeColor() {
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
        for (let i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
            elems[i].classList.add('updatedButton');
            elems[i].classList.remove('button');
        }
    }
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("button5").onclick = changeColor;
};
```

Also, for reference, it is better to use let instead of var. Furthermore, it is better to alter things like onClick in the JS than HTML.